# Rspec request test for a rails 7.0 returns an integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-7, turbo-rails

I have a rails 7.0 application in which I retrieve all the items and display them in the view.

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end
```

In my view I render all the items.

```
<turbo-frame id="content">
  <% @items.each do |item| %>
    <%= render partial: 'items/item', locals: { item: item } %>
  <% end %>
</turbo-frame>
```

Then in my specs I am trying to test the index page.

```
RSpec.describe "Items", type: :request do
  describe "GET /index" do
    subject(:visit_link) { get '/items' }
    context 'when logged in' do
      it 'returns 200' do
      expect(subject).to have_http_status(200)
      #In this point subject has as value the integer 200
```

Do I need any special configuration in order to use rspec with rails 7.0 and hotwired?

Comment: Request specs shouldn't be effected at all - request specs after all just send HTTP requests and don't care about any of the JS trickery. Thats really for feature specs (aka System Tests) which run a browser. This is very wordy though - you can just use `it { should have_http_status(:ok) }` or the generic `it { should be_successful }`  which checks for range of 2XX status codes.

Comment: The rendering is also extremly wordy - you can just do  `<%= render @items %>`  and let the conventions do the work for you. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections